# How do you close open files using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, storing-data, xcode9.1

I am downloading ~1300 images. Those are small images total size is around ~500KB. However, after downloading and putting them into userDefault, I get error as below:

**libsystem_network.dylib: nw_route_get_ifindex :: socket(PF_ROUTE, SOCK_RAW, PF_ROUTE) failed: [24] Too many open files**

Assumingely, downloaded png images are not being closed.

I already extended cache size via below:

```
    // Configuring max network request cache size
    let memoryCapacity = 30 * 1024 * 1024 // 30MB
    let diskCapacity = 30 * 1024 * 1024   // 30MB
    let urlCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: "myDiscPath")
    URLCache.shared = urlCache
```

And this is the approach I got to store images:

```
    func storeImages (){
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: Cur.count, by: 1) {
            // Saving into userDefault
            saveIconsToDefault(row: i)
        }
    }
```

I get the error after all of them being added into userDefault. So, I know they are there.

**EDIT:**

**FUNCTIONS:**

```
func getImageFromWeb(_ urlString: String, closure: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return closure(nil)
    }
    let task = URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return closure(nil)
        }
        guard response != nil else {
            print("no response")
            return closure(nil)
        }
        guard data != nil else {
            print("no data")
            return closure(nil)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            closure(UIImage(data: data!))
        }
    }; task.resume()
}

func getIcon (id: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
    var icon = UIImage()

    let imageUrl = "https://files/static/img/\(id).png"

        getImageFromWeb(imageUrl) { (image) in
            if verifyUrl(urlString: imageUrl) == true {
                if let image = image {
                    icon = image
                    completion(icon)
                }
            } else {
                if let image = UIImage(named: "no_image_icon") {
                    icon = image
                    completion(icon)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CurrencyCell", for: indexPath) as? CurrencyCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    if currencies.count > 0 {
        let noVal = currencies[indexPath.row].rank ?? "N/A"
        let nameVal = currencies[indexPath.row].name ?? "N/A"
        let priceVal = currencies[indexPath.row].price_usd ?? "N/A"

        getIcon(id: currencies[indexPath.row].id!, completion: { (retImg) in
            cell.configureCell(no: noVal, name: nameVal, price: priceVal, img: retImg)
        })
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Don't store `UIImage`s in `UserDefaults`. Never ever. Especially not 1300 images.

Comment: I appreciate your input. However, would not be better if you also point out where to put those?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238139/ios-download-and-save-image-inside-app try this

Comment: Paul, thank you but those are all in Obj-C which I have no experience with. As the question title indicates I am looking for Swift solution. Although, I see that I can use the Apps local data storage folders ie. "temp" folders as such.  Will continue to research.

Comment: @Rob You are right, I provided more code. Thank you.

Comment: @Rob I was looping through my currency array and trying to download each image and store them into user default. Using those functions, instead of directly calling inside cellForRowAt.

Comment: @Rob please excuse my lack of knowledge, I could not figure out how to implement URLSession.shared into existing code I have. I am sure it is easy but could not achieve it.

Comment: I can create array of URLs for images, but I don't know, how I can download them inside single URLSession instance.

Comment: @Rob WOW! This fixed all the retrievals. With this change in the code, now I am able to do get images as fast as assigning them into TableView. That is such a performance boost compare to previous setup. I cannot THANK YOU enough! Amazing! If you like to post your comment as answer, I would mark it might help someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `URLSession(configuration: .default)` syntax is creating a new `URLSession` for each request. Create a single `URLSession` (saving it in some property) and then reuse it for all of the requests. Or, if you're really not doing any custom configuration of the `URLSession`, just use `URLSession.shared`:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    ...
}
task.resume()
```

---

You mention that you're saving 1300 images in `UserDefaults`. That's not the right place to store that type of data nor for that quantity of files. I'd suggest you use the "Caches" folder as outlined in the [File System Programming Guide: The Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1).

```
let cacheURL = try! FileManager.default
    .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    .appendingPathComponent("images")

// create your subdirectory before you try to save files into it
try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: cacheURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
```

Do not be tempted to store them in the "Documents" folder, either. For more information, see [iOS Storage Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/204/).